# How to pass DevOps release secrets to ARM for Key Vault Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I am trying to deploy a key vault with `secretName` and `secretValue` and I have created a variable group in azure devops with all the secrets and I am using the below parameters in parameter file, but when this gets deployed the secret value gets stored as $(secret) and not the password actually stored in the task group in Azure DevOps.

```
  "secretsObject": {

    "value": {

      "secrets": [

        {

          "secretName": "App012",

          "secretValue": "$(mysecret)"

        },
```

and this is what I got in the key vault template:

```
  {

    "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",

    "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/', parameters('secretsObject').secrets[copyIndex()].secretName)]",

    "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",

    "dependsOn": [

      "[concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"

    ],

    "copy": {

      "name": "secretsCopy",

      "count": "[length(parameters('secretsObject').secrets)]"

    },

    "properties": {

      "value": "[parameters('secretsObject').secrets[copyIndex()].secretValue]"

    }

  }

]
```

}

Any idea how to pass the "secretvalue" as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your asking how to leverage your secrets that are stored as a variable group to be deployed securely with your ARM template via Azure DevOps.  If that is the case look at using [Override Template Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops) in your release task.

This would be in the format of -NameOfARMParameter $(NameofDevOpsVariable)

In your case it would be -mysecret $(NameOfDevOpsVariable)

The deployment .json should look like this for parameter declaration:

```
 "secretValue": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "This is for receiving a value from DevOps releases of the secret to be stored in the key vault"
      }
    },
"secretName": {
          "type": "string",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Secret"
          }
        },
```

For the actual deployment

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
  "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName'),'/',parameters('secretName'))]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
  "properties": {
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "value": "[parameters('secretValue')]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults',  variables('keyVaultName'))]"
  ]
},
```

And the parameters file doesn't need to have anything in it if these values will be fed from Dev Ops

Comment: thats correct, this is what ive done,created a variable group in devops with the secret value and secret password then i linked this to the release as a variable group then in my arm template i got in the parameters file as    "secretsObject": {
      "value": {
        "secrets": [
          {
            "secretName": "ActiveDirectory--TenantId",
            "secretValue": "$(ActiveDirectoryID)"
          },
but once devops deploys this release on my portal resource group it creates the secret name fine but the password is shown as : "$(ActiveDirectoryID)" not the actually password

Comment: This is because your parameter file can not look up the definition of the the DevOps variable value inside the json file. It needs to be passed into the file via and override parameter from DevOps via the release task. The ARM parameter doesn't need to be anything special like you are doing above just a name. In fact don't even need to assign it a value. Then the override parameter would "override" your template value with the secret.

Comment: That not working i am getting an error with bad json content found in the logs in the release pipeline. Any idea how what the template and parameter file should look like?      see below for template file

Comment: "resources": [
            {
                "type": "secrets",
                "name": "[parameters('secretName')]",
                "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
                "tags": { "displayName": "secret" },
                "properties": {
                    "value": "[parameters('secretValue')]"
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
                ]     
{

Comment: "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/', parameters('secretsObject').secrets[copyIndex()].secretName)]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "value": "[parameters('secretValue')]"
        }

Comment: and this what i have in template file:
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "keyVaultName": {
        "value": "kvneurdevint01nibraz14"
      },
      "secretValue": {
        "value": ""
      }
    }

Comment: Your deployment .json is not formated for what you are trying to accomplish. What are you doing with the Copy Index? And why does it have to be a secret Object in the parameters file?  It can be just not sure why the need for it. I've updated the answer with the json for the parameter and template file

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a parameter file with the secret / link to Key Vault.

Here's a sample of it:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "adminLogin": {
            "value": "exampleadmin"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "reference": {
              "keyVault": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault-name>"
              },
              "secretName": "ExamplePassword"
            }
        },
        "sqlServerName": {
            "value": "<your-server-name>"
        }
    }
}
```

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/parameter-files

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/add-template-to-azure-pipelines

Comment: the above still shows the password in the parameter file, i want the password as a variable in the parameter file as $mypassword which will be pulled out from the azure devops variable group. also my template creates a new keyvault then inserts all the keys i have specified in the parameter file which is working fine but the password is clearly visible in parameter file hence i want all passwords to be as $variables which will get pulled out from the azure devops variable group

Comment: this is what i have in tempate file:
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/', parameters('secretsObject').secrets[copyIndex()].secretName)]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
      ],
      "copy": {
        "name": "secretsCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('secretsObject').secrets)]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "value": "[parameters('secretsObject').secrets[copyIndex()].secretValue]"

Comment: if you check the sample I gave, it shows the admin password with a link to key vault, which is not the real password. ("id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault-name>"). I've never seen it working as a pipeline variable, I'm not sure if it's possible or not